# Как сделать приложение, считающее километраж поездки?

Tags: android, gps

Как сделать приложение которое будет показывать сколько километров человек проехал, вроде вопрос должен быть популярным, но в поисковике очень много мусора по этому вопросу, не могу отыскать примеры, поэтому буду благодарен за любые ссылки на рабочие решения и личный опыт разработки. Самому велосипед изобретать не хочется потому что боюсь будет много ошибок.

Comment: Ссылки на рабочие решения — это как-то офтопик. А что в этой задаче сложного? (Не, ну понятно, что скопипастить готовое решение всегда легче, но вы ж программист!)

Comment: Там всякие филтры иминитых ученых применяются, чтоб не нужные координаты отбрасывать, а это уже сложно)

Comment: Это уже интереснее. А разве там реально что-то большее, чем усреднение?

Comment: возможно, я не знаю)

Comment: @Gennady вы хотите решить эту задачу, не реализуя ни одного алгоритма? Не выйдет. Готовьтесь учить статистику и теорию графов.

Answer (score 2):

Один из самых популярных https://www.traccar.org/source-code/.

Сервер (листенер):

```
git clone https://github.com/tananaev/traccar.git
```

Android клиент:

```
git clone https://github.com/tananaev/traccar-client-android.git
```

iOS клиент:

```
https://github.com/tananaev/traccar-client-ios.git
```

НО! 50% задачи, даже больше, зависит от самого трекера.

Самый большой ваш враг это *Звездочка* это когда автомобиль стоит на месте и из за погрешности GPS сигнала дает разбойные координаты. за час он может собрать несколько километров, хотя автомобил стоит на месте.

Так же правильно нужно установить трекер на авто. Что бы трекер мог получать точный угол поворота.

Comment: Вы не знаете, там обработка координат (фильтрация) происходит на клиенте или на сервере?

Comment: @Gennady Я использовал Android версию. и было обработка у клиента, тоесть Android приложения сама обрабатывала келометраж и поездки.